# MVC3 links SEO - how to make calls from one controller to other controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, seo, controllers

I have one problem, I am not sure how to explain but I will try.
I followed this: http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/SEO-Friendly-Routes-with-ASPnet-MVC.aspx
And I was able to achieve what they describe. 
But if I have a page where i wish to call action from other controller, it doesn't work.
It doens't show the link in this way: "this-is-my-link" in the URL.

I don't know what do I do wrong?

in Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default2",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{pageTitle}",
            new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    pageTitle = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );

    }
```

Views/Help/FAQ

```
@Html.ActionLink(FaqStrings.ContactUs, "ContactUs", "Home", new { id = 1, pageTitle = "link text".ToSeoUrl() })
```

It says that it can't resolve the ContactUs. Instead of the actions from HomeController, it sees the actions of the HelpController.

In HomeController

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ContactUs()
    {
        var model = new ViewModelContactUs
                        {
                            Resultmessage = string.Empty,
                            Youremail = string.Empty,
                            Yourmessage = string.Empty,
                            Yourname = string.Empty
                        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ContactUs(ViewModelContactUs model)
    {
        Log.DebugFormat("HomeController-ContactUs()");
```

........

```
        var model2 = new ViewModelContactUs
                         {
                             ......
                         };

        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(model2);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  What code doesn't produce the desired result?

Comment: I added the code. I hope it makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your controller into the RouteValues dictionary part of your `@Html.ActionLink`

```
@Html.ActionLink(FaqStrings.ContactUs, "ContactUs", new {controller="Home", id = 1, pageTitle = "link text".ToSeoUrl() })
```

**EDIT**

To address the logic, it has to do with the available signatures of the Html.ActionLink method.  [Here is the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for information but...

The method signature that you were using was `Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action", "Contoller", RouteValues, HtmlAttributes)`.  Since you were not passing HtmlAttributes, it was matching up wrong and generating the wrong link.  By either moving the controller into the `RouteValuesDictionary` or passing a `, null` at the end of your call should solve it.  But, I personally don't like throwing nulls around unless I need to, so I typically just define the controller in the `RouteValuesDictionary`.

If you were not passing any RouteValues, then a call to `Html.ActionLink("Link Text", Action, Controller)` works with no issues.

Hope that clears it up a little! :)

Comment: That was correct, thank you very much! What is the logic? I think I get it but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: I updated the answer a little to try and explain what is going on (to the best of my ability anyways).

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is that:

```
@Html.ActionLink(FaqStrings.ContactUs, 
                 "ContactUs", 
                 "Home", 
                 new { id = 1, pageTitle = "link text".ToSeoUrl() })
```

Will produce an `Anchor` which when clicked will produce an `HTTP GET`, however you're method is requiring `HTTP POST`:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]  // <-----POST
public ActionResult ContactUs(ViewModelContactUs model)
```